# Error Code 10060 in a Winforms application using Sockets (TCP)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a server program and a client program. I built it based from the appliation from [this tutorial](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html). The thing is, it works (connects successfully and communicates) when I run both the program on the same computer. But when I tried running the client app in a different computer from where the server runs and connect it to the server app, this exception happens:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 169.254.212.31:1986

I made sure that the client app will connect to the IP Address that the Server App listens to. I am running my application in a LAN. What should I do to resolve this problem?

UPDATE:
I'm sorry, forgot to put the link of the tutorial I was talking about. [Here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html) it is.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by opening a port (in my case, Port 1986).

I followed this guide:
[How to open a port in windows 7 firewall](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html)